# iOS UITableViewCell not correctly update after scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

Here's what im having: I have a TableView with custom UITableViewCell, it's loading the data from an MutableArray.

In my cellForRow: i call the code to draw a subview with the data from the array, when i scroll down and scroll up, that subview appear very wrong, but every label appear to be correct...

I have tried many answer around google but all doesnt solve it, i even put the subview to the array but doesnt work too,sorry i cant post image yet :(

```
NSMutableArray *mintHistoryList = //Array of Epin objects 

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
// Configure the cell...

EPinObject *data;

if (indexPath.row < self.mintHistoryList.count && [[self.mintHistoryList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isKindOfClass:[EPinObject class]])
    {
        data = [self.mintHistoryList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        UILabel *pinGeneratedDateLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
        pinGeneratedDateLabel.text = data.pinGeneratedTime;

        UILabel *pinNumberLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
        pinNumberLabel.text = data.pinCode;

        UILabel *pinOriginalLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
        pinOriginalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [Common currencyFloatRemake:data.pinOriginalAmount],[Common currencyCodeToSymbol:data.pinCurrencyCode]];
        pinOriginalLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
        pinOriginalLabel.minimumScaleFactor=0.5;

        UILabel *pinLeftLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:103];
        pinLeftLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@ left", [Common currencyFloatRemake:data.pinLeftAmount],[Common currencyCodeToSymbol:data.pinCurrencyCode]];
        pinLeftLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
        pinLeftLabel.minimumScaleFactor=0.5;

        //THIS PART

        UIView *circleView = (UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:104];
        [circleView addSubview:[Customview alloc]initWithOriginal:data.pinOriginalAmount andLeft:data.pinLeftAmount];  
    }
```

The array does not change, other label also does not change, only the subview is not correct

Correct:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwtBKpSMH_eHUWRfMkpzOTFaTkE/view?usp=sharing

Scroll down and up:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwtBKpSMH_eHWkxmeDNGQUJvdnM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: what font is that status bar? :D

Comment: Show your cell's initialization and fix links, pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think problem is here

```
UIView *circleView = (UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:104];
[circleView addSubview:[Customview alloc]initWithOriginal:data.pinOriginalAmount andLeft:data.pinLeftAmount];
```

When you will reuse cell it will contain 2 circleView...
You should remove the previous one, or reuse circleView itself

PS Images is not available for me, I receive error 403

Comment: how can i reuse it? i knew its there but i cant find a way to do it. it seems that the cell rendering is slow so that it cause wrong, thanks

Comment: Sorry, fixed the links

Comment: @Tj3n just clear circleView before add new subview: `[[circleView subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)]`

Comment: thanks, i put it under UIView *circleView = (UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:104]; and it works!

Comment: And one more thing! :)
It's a bad practise to use viewWithTag.
Normally you should inherit your own cell from UITableViewCell and make some methods like:
[myCell setPinNumber: number];
[myCell pinLeftValue: value];
etc...

Comment: Is it better performance than use the viewWithTag?, i knew about making the External class and make Xib but not sure the performance